# export Intellij Idea scala static analysis rules into a scalastyle_configuration file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalastyle

I want to keep the predefined static analysis rules from Intellij Idea in a scalastyle_configuration file and run the check at prepush githook in order to enforce those rules across our team. Is there a standard way to do so ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to run IntelliJ inspections via Scalastyle?

Comment: Yes, exactly. i'ts also fine to enforce other standard code style like twitter's via Scalastyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ inspections aren't based on ScalaStyle. But you can run them standalone or from a CI server using the `inspect.sh` or `inspect.bat` scripts from your IntelliJ installation with the following parameters:

- project file path
- inspection profile path
- output path

OSX example:

```
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin/inspect.sh ~/IntelliJ IDEAProjects/MyTestProject ~/Library/Preferences/ideaXX/inspection/Default.xml ~/IntelliJ IDEAProjects/MyTestProject/results-dir -v2
```

For more details, see the documentation on how to run them standalone:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/running-inspections-offline.html#d2149225e24

Or from TeamCity:
https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Inspections

Comment: Is there any way to run them from bitbucket pipeline or jenkins ?

Comment: Sure, the same you would run any script. You just need the inspection profile to be available on the server.